# Android usb permissions. How to handle attach, detach and already plugged in

Tags: android, qt, permissions, usb

I'm developing an android app that must communicate with a usb device. I read the docs at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html, and added an intent filter and a device list. After that my app detects the device when I plug it in and offers to start the app automatically. If the app is already running when the device is plugged, or if the device is already plugged when I start the app, there are problems.

If the app is already running I get a new blank window. I suspected it started another instance and added android:launchMode="singleTask" to my manifest, but the behavior did not change. I think I get an error message: E/Qt JAVA ( 6433): Surface 1 not found!

If the device is already plugged when I start the app, I get a permission error when I try to open the device.

The behavior I would like is:
- If dev attached when app not running, start the app
- If dev attached when app running, detect it and enumerate devices
- If dev detached when app running, detect and handle it in my code

Should all this be doable just with the intent filter if I do it correctly?

I'm developing the app with Qt, and using JNI to interface java code handling the usb stuff, if that is relevant info.

Comment: I changed android:launchMode="singleTask"  to android:launchMode="singleInstance" and put it in the right place in my manifest. That solved it.

Comment: But, all is not solved yet. If the device is already plugged nothing happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `android:launchMode` to `singleInstance`, not `singleTask`.

From [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html):

`singleTask`:

> The system creates the activity at the root of a new task and routes the intent to it. However, if an instance of the activity already exists, the system routes the intent to existing instance through a call to its onNewIntent() method, rather than creating a new one.

`singleInstance`:

> Same as "singleTask", except that the system doesn't launch any other activities into the task holding the instance. The activity is always the single and only member of its task.